# Clickonce installer - Cannot download application

Tags: .net, download, windows-installer, installation, clickonce

I trying to help somebody out with a problem they are having - The Clickonce installer cannot download the application. The Clickonce installer works for all the other people.
I have a copy of the log that is created when the installer is run.

```html
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.50938'
Setting value '4.5.50938 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50938 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://acarsng.com/download/ACARSng.application'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the antivirus or the proxy that blocks the download of the file.
Try to write the address on your browser

'http://acarsng.com/download/ACARSng.application'

and checks to see if the download is done.
Or try disabling your antivirus and run the setup.

Comment: Yes it downloads properly. I did not think about antivirus or the proxy yet. I will try that and report back to you.

Comment: Yes it started working somehow. We tried a few settings in Windows and got it to work.